# iOS app doesn't work when opening and closing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple app built that has some animations using CALayers, music playing in the background and UIScrollViews.

The app works fine when it launches, however once I press the home button and open the app again, the animations don't work. All the CALayers return to their initial points and don't move.

The code for the animations is in the `-(void)viewDidLoad` method. I'm thinking that maybe it should be in a different section.

I want everything to happen on load. Oddly enough, the code for the music and the animation of the background works - however anything on a CALayer reverts to original position.

Code:

Note that the Audio plays again when reloaded and the UIImageView animation works, but not the CALayers.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

scroll1.alpha = 0;
scroll2.alpha = 0;
scroll3.alpha = 0;


//audio play
NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/Mermaid.mp3"];
NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
NSError* err;

//Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
          [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

if( err ){
    //bail!
    NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
}
else{
    //set our delegate and begin playback
    [player play];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    player.currentTime = 0;
    player.volume = .75;
}

NSArray *animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-01.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-02.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-03.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-04.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-05.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-06.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-07.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-08.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-07.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-06.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-05.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-04.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-03.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-02.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"imga-01.png"],
                            nil];

viewer = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:viewer];
viewer.animationImages = animationImages ;
viewer.animationDuration= 5;
[viewer startAnimating];

//blimp

UIImage *blimpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blimp.png"];

blimp = [CALayer layer];
blimp.contents = (id)blimpImage.CGImage;
blimp.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 188,65);
blimp.position = CGPointMake(0,
                             170);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:blimp];

CGPoint startPt1 = CGPointMake(-100,
                               blimp.position.y);
CGPoint endPt1 = CGPointMake(500,
                             blimp.position.y);

CABasicAnimation *anim1 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim1.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
anim1.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPt1];
anim1.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPt1];
anim1.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim1.duration = 14.0;
[blimp addAnimation:anim1 forKey:@"position"];



//cloud2

UIImage *cloudandImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloud.png"];

cloud2 = [CALayer layer];
cloud2.contents = (id)cloudandImage.CGImage;
cloud2.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, cloudandImage.size.width, cloudandImage.size.height);
cloud2.position = CGPointMake(0,
                              200);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:cloud2];

CGPoint startPt2 = CGPointMake(500,
                               cloud2.position.y);
CGPoint endPt2 = CGPointMake(-100,
                             cloud2.position.y);

CABasicAnimation *anim2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim2.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
anim2.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPt2];
anim2.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPt2];
anim2.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim2.duration = 10.0;
[cloud2 addAnimation:anim2 forKey:@"position"];



//Sailboat1
UIImage *boatimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boat.png"];

boat = [CALayer layer];

boat.contents = (id)boatimage.CGImage;

boat.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 110);
boat.position = P(160, 25);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:boat];


UIBezierPath *trackPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[trackPath moveToPoint:P(-200, 490)];
[trackPath addCurveToPoint:P(180, 470)
             controlPoint1:P(60, 410)
             controlPoint2:P(120, 480)];

[trackPath addCurveToPoint:P(400, 470)
             controlPoint1:P(210, 465)
             controlPoint2:P(270, 440)];

CAKeyframeAnimation *anim3 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim3.path = trackPath.CGPath;
anim3.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
anim3.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim3.duration = 4.7;
[boat addAnimation:anim3 forKey:@"race"];

//Playbutton
[self.view addSubview:playButton];

//scroll1
scroll1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000,1000);
[self.view addSubview:scroll1];

//scroll2
scroll2.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000,1000);
[self.view addSubview:scroll2];

//scroll3
scroll3.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000,1000);
[self.view addSubview:scroll3];






[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self
                               selector:@selector(animationDone:)
                               userInfo:nil repeats:NO];





}
```

Comment: Maybe you'll need to save the state of the app and on restart pick where you have left off.

Comment: OK, I'm 5 days new to Objective-C, how do you suggest I do this? If you need to see some of the code let me know. Thanks A lot!

Comment: Sure...and yes, some code would be nice and easier trying to help you out.

Comment: I'm looking into your code right now and will try to help you out, but have you considered using SpriteKit? It's a lot easier and I'll do exactly what you want with much less effort.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is called exactly once, when the view controller is first loaded into memory. This is where you want to instantiate any instance variables and build any views that live for the entire lifecycle of this view controller. However, the view is usually not yet visible at this point.

`viewDidAppear` is called when the view is actually visible, and can be called multiple times during the lifecycle of a View Controller (for instance, when a Modal View Controller is dismissed and the view becomes visible again). This is where you want to perform any layout actions or do any drawing in the UI - for example, presenting a modal view controller. However, anything you do here should be repeatable. It's best not to retain things here, or else you'll get memory leaks if you don't release them when the view disappears.

viewWillAppear gets called every time the view appears.

For more details see the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Also see [this](http://prateekvjoshi.com/2013/12/06/difference-between-viewdidload-viewwillappear-and-viewdidappear/). Read these you'll know where you should put your code. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that `viewDidAppear` is not being called when the app becomes active from standby.

Comment: @Daniel so the problem is that when I close the app from the home button (Putting it into standby) and then reopen it, the animations don't work. Is there something else I should do to make it activate from standby?

Comment: Rashad, the link you posted was very useful, thanks. I was able to speed up the load time significantly. However, the animations still don't load when the app is opened and closed.

Answer (score 0):

actually you're not calling `[super viewDidAppear:animated]` which is a must as mentioned in apples [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW17). This could cause in unexpected results.

> You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated with presenting the view. If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

Comment: I added [super viewDidAppear:animated]; to my code however the animations of the CALayers still don't work after reloading.

Comment: could this have anything to do with the timer?